# App getting reloaded on navigating to a route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components

I am working on an angular2 application where **on login I want to navigate to a specific route**. Now I have a function defined for the login and what it simply does is calls a service which checks the credentials passed in form.

I am sharing the service as well as my loginComponent:

**LoginFormComponent:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ShareService} from './ShareService'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'login',
 template: `

      <div class="container">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" #username required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="alterEgo">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" #password id="alterEgo">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="submit(username,password)">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>

 `
 })
 export class LoginFormComponent {

   admin_name="Admin";
   admin_password="Password";
   loginadmin:boolean;

   constructor(private _shareService:ShareService,private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) 
   {}


   submit(name:HTMLInputElement,pass:HTMLInputElement){
        this._shareService.submit(name.value,pass.value);

        if(this._shareService.getData())
        {
          this.router.navigate(['about']);
        }
   }

 }
```

**ShareService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()


 export class ShareService {

   updateComponent:EventEmitter=new EventEmitter();

   loginadmin:boolean;

   submit(name:string,pass:string):boolean{
     if(this.admin_name===name.value  && this.admin_password===pass.value){
     this.loginadmin=true;
     this.updateComponent.emit(this.loginadmin);
     }
     return false;
   }

   getData():boolean{
     return this.loginadmin;
   }


 }
```

The `about` which you can see in `this.router.navigate` in `loginFormComponent` is route configured in `app module`. Sharing the route configuration as well:

**app module**:

```
const routes:Routes=[
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'contactus', redirectTo: 'contact' },
  { path: '', component:LandingComponent } 
 ];
```

And here's my simple **about component**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'about',
 template: `<h1>Welcome about!</h1>`
 })
 export class AboutComponent {
 }
```

Now the problem is it gets authenticated but as soon as I click on login it just reloads the application inplace of navigating to `about` component.

Can someone tell me as to what I am doing wrong here. Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your form is actually posting to iteslf like a regular form would instead of angular catching it and doing what it needs to. Have you tried having a form submit and then making the button just a submit button.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="submit(username,password)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" #username required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="alterEgo">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" #password id="alterEgo">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to add something to your solution that took me a while to figure out. In the submit method, you need to return false to not propagate the event. I had problems with the page reloading when trying to navigate to a different route on the submit button

Comment: Hmm I've had that problem with links or other buttons but it seemed to be fine with my forms and a submit button.